# trace incoming call generates error in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

in my application i try to trace an incoming call using AbstractPhoneListener.
The call gets traced but the problem is that it generates an error and i have to exit the simulator

I tested on device but when a call arrives nothing happens as i have tried to do!!!!

ERROR = "Access violation reading from 0x00000004"

code:

```
public class CallTrace extends AbstractPhoneListener
{


    CallTrace()
    {

    }


    public void callIncoming(int callId)
    {
        PhoneCall call = Phone.getCall(callId);
        String callNumber = call.getDisplayPhoneNumber();l

        System.out.println("call traced!!!!!!!!");

    }   

}
```

code:

```
public class BackgroundListener extends Thread 
{  
    private static PersistentObject timeStore,NPZstore;
    private static Vector timeVector,mode;
    static CallTrace calltrace;
    String[] time1,time2;
    int time1Flag=0,time2Flag=0;

     public BackgroundListener()
     {   
         calltrace = new CallTrace();
     Phone.addPhoneListener(calltrace); 
         this.start();
     }
     boolean stopThread = false;

     public void run()
     {
          while (!stopThread)
          {   
        //do some coding here like matching of dates etc.that works well    
               try
               {
                   sleep(6000) ;
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                    System.out.println("exception in background thread:"+e);
               }
          }
     }

     public synchronized void stop()
     {
          stopThread = true;
     }
     protected void onExit()
     {
          this.stop();
     }
  }
```

code:

```
public class HomeScreen extends UiApplication implements GlobalEventListener
{
    private static PersistentObject NPZstore;
    private static Vector mode;
    static boolean modeValue=false;
    static BackgroundListener obj;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(args!=null && args[0].equals("gui"))
        {
            HomeScreen homescreen = new HomeScreen();
            homescreen.enterEventDispatcher();
        }
        else
        {
          obj = new BackgroundListener();       
        }
    }
    HomeScreen()
    {
        pushScreen(new WorkScreen());
    }


public void eventOccurred(long guid, int data0, int data1, Object object0,
  Object object1)
        {

    }
}
class WorkScreen extends MainScreen 
{
    CustomButtonField REDbutton,GREENbutton;
    HorizontalFieldManager hfmRED,hfmGREEN;
    private static PersistentObject NPZstore;
    private static Vector mode;
    boolean modeValue=false;
    static CallTrace calltrace;
    PopupScreen selectBluetoothType;
    final Bitmap background2;

    public WorkScreen()
    {
    //adding some fields here   
        }       
}
```

Comment: the concept of main works with autostartup and system module

Comment: i dont think there is any problem in this code.Run clean.bat from simulator folder.

Comment: i tried that too but no success!!!!!I found something strange.If i run this on simulator without using any breakpoint then error pops up but if i run using breakpoints to test the code and try to disconnect the incomming call before code inside incomming call gets completed then no error pops up.what to do.Please help

Comment: code is working fine for me except ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. 
i have changed like this.
 if(args!=null && args.length > 0 && "gui".equals(args[0])){
            HomeScreen homescreen = new HomeScreen();
            homescreen.enterEventDispatcher();
        }

Comment: well i dont get any such error as u say.but still this code is safe.still my problem is same.don't understand whats going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Windows error caused by the simulator crashing.  So it's not a bug in your code but probably a bug in the simulator.  I'd suggest [downloading and installing a different simulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) - even if it's the same model pick the latest build.  The simulators that ship with the JDE are usually quite dated.